# Filtering Records From Database

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, join

I have 4 tables in database

1. `Users` with columns `Id, Email, Password, Active`
2. `InformationData` with columns `Id, Title, Description, Link`
3. `Filters` with columns `Id, Keyword, Active`
4. `LUserToFilter` with columns `UserId, FilterId`

Now what I want is to filter specific records from `InformationData` table in which title and description does not contains keywords from filters table and we select those filters from `LUserToFilter` table based on a specific user id.

I tried this query but it only returns those records which contains that filtered keywords and not return the other records.

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[SP_GetFilteredData]
@userid int
as
begin
select D.* from Filters f
inner join LUsersToFilters L on L.FilterId=F.Id
inner join InformationData D on D.Title like '%'+F.KeyWord+'%' or D.Description like '%'+F.KeyWord+'%'
where L.UserId=@userid
end
```

Any suggestion please..

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Ok sorry for using sp_ and for english writing but writing english in this way is my habit I will try to get rid of it

Comment: I'm still not entirely clear what you want to filter out (e.g. not show), and what rows you want to show. Did I understand correctly: you want to **show** those rows from `InformationData` that **do not contain** any of the words from `Filters` in either their title or description columns?

Comment: I need exactly what you understand..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT D.* FROM InformationData D
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
   (SELECT * FROM Filters F INNER JOIN LUsersToFilters L ON F.id=L.FilterId
    WHERE (D.Title LIKE '%'+F.KeyWord+'%' OR D.Description LIKE '%'+F.KeyWord+'%')
    AND L.userid = @userid)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[SP_GetFilteredData]
@userid int
as
begin
select D.* from Filters f
    inner join LUsersToFilters L on L.FilterId=F.Id
    inner join InformationData D on NOT (D.Title like '%'+F.KeyWord+'%') AND NOT (D.Description like '%'+F.KeyWord+'%')
where L.UserId=@userid
end
```

Comment: Does not work for me but thanks for answer i solve my issue and also post the answer.. `SELECT D.* FROM InformationData D WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Filters F INNER JOIN LUsersToFilters L ON F.id=L.FilterId WHERE (D.Title LIKE '%'+F.KeyWord+'%' OR D.Description LIKE '%'+F.KeyWord+'%') AND L.userid = @userid)`